# How to unzip carved files from disk in raw format

Tags: compression, computer-forensics

Sorry for making such an unclear title
I have a disk image disk.raw from which I carved deleted files using Sleuth Kit and its command `blkls disk.raw 1-8000 > carved` which put into a file the data in the unallocated blocks from 1 to 8000 (where I know my deleted files are)

So my output is a file containing some data and many empty spaces in between. For example, if I open it on a notepad, I get texts like these :

```
1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               4                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               µ½;ÓóÆJv4éA°¿S*îÔy÷è„¡d:ÄÕÔˆÈ¤ÒX2ÛK]8øâ†+[ÛÖ7jiº;Îàdƒ”ÜRÒ€
¥¾‘…Î»5y)‹F¹ž8rÀÉø±9ŸÎ:ÿf¤$cªW›
jÈ‰…j,Ü¬3®°d¥²¥®:Þ FhãŽß[ÔÀZ
÷·Îâ#§B¢† Uƒ†=qÁ[Ðµ#Sy(JØš#œKÊÏ9êþáð0•›nÊÑ=q­¡ŽšOk'ë#ëÚšÚjN1V&l?Hù´m,0ã¼•(nôTúèªÎb4z
„áñP$¼YèÐ%É‚YSÄÔÎ”ú%ióÎƒP¥ð"÷…ž8«¾oÀE‚f¤X§üS(‘Àº.8H§÷ëü1¥ãùBÁ
ÏÉÎµ”˜Ê<wªf”œàºš¯+kô¨§
÷*ÎÛMøÈ”Âqú2>XME[9¿
[æÀ‹dJ¹—×™
@¦e³ž‹
&ýãY
™qA›¥ì„5šI‰h{?–hZ%"?mÓ{ƒÌ‡5mf
R‹sàì‰;½˜\E€Îñ$‡jYÀK%ØnDwí[=û   Ú‘;1„LQP!ðè.¦(w
‘ªb,†ä‚ž8®©8¢BMMã×›Œx
£®‘ÚFëÖÐ±gi·ÖŠ.O&ÂëR¹5–{íy˜÷æ¡žÜç¦^ñbj˜1Úî5G)©Äš¸#¡
? qâ1q[µ­£É>½¥f–#žÞPžR›#T3lÂ.DcSÚË¥Ñ¹‹e¬·!$ù­“àYž{¨Ü˜ÉbJ…8¬‘#"b 3Ø„¤Í
qµ~#©Á42û,èLE²‰Iv+Áƒ™MšÅÄ
$Bn×ÖXya1£²ŒJçj-Õ7 :AÚ0è@eP@sef}@NÈ­è?¸¯ãß8µ#Q?ÒYÍ†Û¡)†ë3F›Œ[ŽF®8©!PóÚª]p   [íˆyÊn;ãÕ§rBvÏŸ`‚È¨ŠöMë÷S¸50¦è€\¾i'7ÒÚTT•vˆ›™¸ë‹ƒÞS>ðºjû&]WÆ–˜ÚÔG•5ÚÑÎ¥Vñ`;´0æ6\wuo«íîÕµ¬t–‚Âþ‘)ü¨Òíi¼_¡•o_iùab›,âezkM#Þ­æ]–h6Š¨+S$"4”4^ÞóD*í£0Ìmk¼@G•¨pG‡Ï{âˆ‰ŒB™ƒ)1Y¸E1<1¼
S’5éà‚z[A¬TD‰·Ý¾é   m2ËTÍÌšÛrvF€Â«j¤ô?ÿþ­¢Zh4œ6<åŠ•n´öñ>ï9Ì}
```

I know that those bunch of data represents a compressed file. Is there a way for me to decode these and read the files inside ? Is there a tool that does that given this previous input ?

I'm really new to this and have basic knowledge :)

Thank you kindly in advance,

Comment: Errr, Notepad isn't the world's best binary editor, try https://hexed.it/

Comment: Yes, please don't ever put garbled binary in a question. It is useless, since loss has been incurred in trying to "print" the binary. The original is not recoverable. Use hexadecimal or Base64 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes carved files lose their headers format, repairing it might lead to the file being accessible again. As mentioned by [Mark Setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell) using a hex editor is better than a notepad. Make sure also to look for the correct header and save the file again with the correct format. Hopefully this is helpful.